# Using querysets properly

Tags: django, satchmo

I'm pretty sure the following code can be done much more efficiently using querysets. I just don't know how. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(contact=contact)
for order in orders:
    for item in order.orderitem_set.all():
        if cartitem.product_id == item.product_id:
            return True
return False
```

Many thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) and [lookups spanning relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
Order.objects.filter(contact=contact, 
                     order_item__product=cartitem.product_id).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks okm! This is what I needed ultimately:      **Order.objects.filter(contact=contact, orderitem__product=cartitem.product_id).exists()** I'm not sure why product_id had to become product, but in any event it works now.

Comment: @user1294974  fixed. No idea why `_id` does not work, it normally should for FK. But yes `product` always works and shorter in code.

Comment: @user1294974 Welcome to Stack Overflow! Now that you've solved your problem with okm's answer, make sure to mark it as accepted using the green checkmark.